# How to improve a mysql COUNT query for speed?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count, query-optimization

How can I improve this query for speed? at the moment it's taking a couple of seconds only to load the php file where the query is without even querying anything.

I've an index on skillsTrends, jobtitle and industry.
Collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

```
$sql = "SELECT 
   COUNT(skillsTrends), 
   skillsTrends,
   jobtitle,
   industry,
   industry_url 
FROM fr_skills_trends 
WHERE industry IN ('". implode("', '", $industryInsertSql). "') 
  AND LENGTH(skillsTrends)<=35 
  AND reg_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH 
GROUP BY skillsTrends ORDER by LENGTH(skillsTrends) DESC";
```

Number of records < 1,000,000.

Comment: I am getting an error `ERROR 1140 (42000)`.  This is because of  "MySQL 5.7.5 and later implements detection of functional dependence. If the [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) mode is enabled (which it is by default),"

Comment: "I've an index on .... jobtitle " Do you really think that helps?  What about `reg_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH` ? Does that not need an index on `reg_date`?  And `LENGTH(skillsTrends)<=35` ?...... BTW: How does the contents of `$industryInsertSql` look like ?

Comment: BTW: Someone wrote a chapter about this subject, see: [8.2.1 Optimizing SELECT Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-optimization.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. $industryInsertSql is a category e.g. Accounting that comes from a select option menu. Under that category there can be a few thousands records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [covering index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html).

```
CREATE INDEX fr_skills_trends_date_industry 
          ON fr_skills_trends 
             (reg_date , industry, skillsTrends);
```

It should help the performance of your query.

And, your query misuses [MySQL's notorious nonstandard extension to GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html).  Try this instead.

```sql
SELECT 
   COUNT(skillsTrends), 
   skillsTrends,
   jobtitle,
   industry,
   industry_url 
FROM fr_skills_trends 
WHERE industry IN ('". implode("', '", $industryInsertSql). "') 
  AND LENGTH(skillsTrends)<=35 
  AND reg_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH 
GROUP BY skillsTrends, jobtitle, industry, industry_url
ORDER by LENGTH(skillsTrends) DESC
```

Comment: Blazingly fast, thanks. I was also about to update the index as mentioned by Luuk. One thing, I can't see the difference between your query and mine, but I've used it.